# Rails server killed when requesting a preview

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloud9-ide

I am working on M.Hartl's rails tutorial and I opted out for using the cloud9 IDE instead of the local server in order to focus on learning rails and not worry about working on the server.

This is the crash error that I am getting:

```
thermobee:~/workspace/sample_app (filling-in-layout) $ rails s -b $IP -p $PORT
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:8080
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2015-12-15 05:19:02] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-12-15 05:19:02] INFO  ruby 2.2.1 (2015-02-26) [x86_64-linux]
[2015-12-15 05:19:02] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=14300 port=8080


Started GET "/" for 174.113.76.61 at 2015-12-15 05:19:25 +0000
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
  Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (192.2ms)
Killed
```

It kept happening throughout the day. I would add code and it would sometimes get stuck saving the file and sometimes it the server would get killed as I try to view the work I've done so far. Every time I would get stuck at a different point as I kept deleting the git branch I was working on.

I apologize for the long winded question, but I did not know how to formulate this properly as there has been a lot going on. I can provide any files that would help solve this and I can also give you read access to the IDE files as well.

Comment: Judging from that IP, doesn't look like it's a local server. And what do you mean deleting git branches? How is that related?

Comment: Its odd really. I started a new branch with the latest chapter, which happens to be learning how to add scss to the app and this problem kept happening at various depths into the work. Since I had a new branch I would just delete it and restart from the beginning since I thought I did something wrong. I've redone it a couple of times and I can say for certain its not me. Its like the system is getting overloaded or something.

Comment: Why are you accessing it from a live IP? What if you just start it with `rails s`?

Comment: It is started with rails s, but as I mentioned in the original post its written in a cloud IDE and its hosted by them.

Comment: Ok, your title is somewhat misleading then. Set up a local serve instead if that IDE is giving you grief.

Comment: I apologize, Im going to correct it. And yeah I agree with you, Im going to set it up tomorrow morning and start over.

Comment: There are many people that have gone through this tutorial over at https://community.c9.io so I'd suggest you ask this there and someone will be able to help out.

Comment: Thank you @BradyDowling, will do.